# How to delete dictionary keys that have a blank value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Currently, I'm working on a script (3.9) that takes a .csv file, and creates a .json file out of it. The original code is as follows...

```
import csv
import json
from time import time

start = time()


def make_json(csv_path, json_path):
    data = []

    with open(csv_path, encoding='utf-8') as csvp:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvp)

        for row in csv_reader:
            data.append(row)

    with open(json_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonp:
        jsonp.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


csv_path = r'elearningtest.csv'
json_path = r'elearningtest.json'

make_json(csv_path, json_path)

print(f'Time taken to run: {time() - start} seconds')
```

This here works as expected. Here's a sample of the output...

```
[
    {
        "username": "username0001",
        "course_code": "coursecode_001",
        "enrollment_date": "7/28/2015 16:16",
        "completion_date": "8/28/2019 11:20",
        "score": ""
    },
    {
        "username": "username0002",
        "course_code": "coursecode_001",
        "enrollment_date": "7/28/2015 16:18",
        "completion_date": "8/7/2019 17:20",
        "score": "78"
    },
    {
        "username": "username0003",
```

However, what I'd like is the following:

```
[
    {
        "username": "username0001",
        "course_code": "coursecode_001",
        "enrollment_date": "7/28/2015 16:16",
        "completion_date": "8/28/2019 11:20"
    },
    {
        "username": "username0002",
        "course_code": "coursecode_001",
        "enrollment_date": "7/28/2015 16:18",
        "completion_date": "8/7/2019 17:20",
        "score": "78"
    },
    {
        "username": "username0003",
```

As you can see in the first entry, the value of the `"score"` key was `""`. What I'm aiming for is, if the value is `""`, it simply won't include that key for that row. This is the code I've done to accomplish this.

```
for row in csv_reader:
    for k, v in row.items():
        if v == "":
            del row[k]
        else:
            data.append(row)
```

When I run this, I get the error of `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

I've looked all over, and have found some promising leads, but nothing that solidly helps with this. Any input from the community would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you're iterating over `row.items()` and changing the items in `row` at the same time. There are a couple ways to get around this:

1. Create a copy of `row.items()` before iterating over it.

```
for row in csv_reader:
    row_items = list(row.items())
    for k, v in row_items:
        if v == "":
            del row[k]
    # Append row to data after checking all keys
    data.append(row)
```

2. Create a new dictionary containing only those values that aren't blank instead of deleting keys from the old one:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    row_filtered = {k: v for k, v in row.items() if v != ""} 
    # this line can also be written as:
    # dict(item for item in row.items() if item[1] != "")    

    # Then append the filtered row
    data.append(row_filtered)
```

Comment: This was perfect, just don't have the 'rep' to give it a up tick. Thank you a ton tho, this was killin' me for days.